# Start a CMD, then echo off of it, then clear the screen

Tags: batch-file

Here are the steps I need, I am using a batch script

1. Open a cmd with path set to the desktop
2. Then set it's echo off
3. Then clear the screen
4. Then wait for me to type commands

So I can enter the commands directly without a long line blocking the view

Code I tried so far

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop"
cls
cmd
@echo off
cls
```

But when I run this I get a typical CMD window, where I have to type "echo off" & "cls" again to get a clean window.

The output I get is

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>
```

The output I want is simple

Imagine a blinking underscore

```
_
```

Thank you.

Comment: try `cls` - This will clear the screen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this line:

```
start /D "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop" cmd /k "prompt $"
```

`/D <path>` will set your working directory

`Prompt $` will set your prompt to "nothing", only the blinking cursor will display

Answer (score 2):

> The output I want is simple
>    _

You can achive this with the `prompt` command, e.g. `prompt $S` or `prompt $g`

Here's an example batch file that would open up a new cmd window with an empty prompt:

```
@echo Off
start cmd /k "prompt $g"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Michael, but where should I put `prompt $S` ? What I really want is a working empty command prompt. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: I tried '@echo off cd "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop" cls cmd prompt $S @echo off cls' And I get the same output

Comment: @Stephan I was trying to open a command window using the cmd command. @Michael, thanks it works, but as I can't vote two answers as the accepted and, this shows a `>` sign on the window, I chose @Stephan's answer. Thanks a lot , I appreciate your quick answer :)

Answer (score 1):

create a VBS file using notepad

add this lines

```
Set cmd = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

cmd.run"cmd"
WScript.Sleep 200

cmd.Sendkeys"echo off{Enter}"
WScript.Sleep 200

cmd.Sendkeys"cls{Enter}"
WScript.Sleep 200
```

Answer (score 1):

This command can be very problematic (cmd /c "echo off | clip")
USE WITHOUT QUOTES:

```
cmd /c  echo off | clip
goto off
```

(Save as .bat)
No more problems !!!

Comment: @mrtux What does clip have to do with this question? I'm asking you as I'm fairly certain alex3518 won't answer and you edited this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just used

```
cls
echo off
cls
cmd|echo off
cls
```

in a batch file. Works for me